# Lines over data in Excel 2007 Scatter Graph

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have some data that needs plotting in a scatter graph in Excel 2007.  However, I need another line (for some arbitrary function - e.g. using trendline will not work) that is represented by a second set of data plotted with no data point markers but a line (it could be smoothed or not, depending on the plot) that sits visually above the data points from the first data series.  This seems simple, but changing the visual order doesn't work.  Any ideas?

(As an example, plot a series like:

```
0   1   1
1   1.1 1.1
2   1.2 1.2
3   1.3 1.3
4   1.4 1.4
5   1.5 1.5
```

...with column 1 being the x-axis, column 2 being the data points and column 3 being the data for the line.  This then, even after changing the order, gives:

[image: I would like the line over the data!]

Comment: No, I want the line to be on top, such that the data points would be mostly hidden.  On my normal dataset there would be hundreds of underlying points, and I want to clearly be able to see the trended data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the red line to overlay the blue data points I selected Scatter with only Markers first and then Change Series Chart Type for the red data series to Scatter with Straight Lines. Not sure whether this is the sort of result you want:

[image: SU511786 example]

so I have not bothered to work out whether the result you show might be as above but in a different order!